# AngularJs - ng-class not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-include

I'm new to Angular and still learning. I've created 'header.html' file and include it in my other html files using 'ng-include'. inside my 'header.html', I have a nav bar and I want nav bar links active with the active page. i tried hard and still couldn't get done. much appreciate if someone could help me to figure this out. thanks.

*header.html*

```
<body ng-app="headerModule">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" ng-controller="headerContr">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class:{ active: isActive('/index.html')};"  href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class:{ active: isActive('/aboutus.html')};"  href="./aboutus.html"><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About Us</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class:{active: isActive('/contactus.html')};" href="./contactus.html"><span class="fa fa-address-book fa-lg"></span> Contact us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container fluid">
           <div class="row">

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

*app.js*

```
var angApp = angular.module('angApp', []);
var headerModule = angular.module('headerModule', []);

headerModule.controller('headerContr', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I resolved the problem, I had used two different angular modules for my 'header.html' and other html pages. when i used the same module it worked. thanks again for everyone who answered me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use `ng-class` in the HTML:

1. As an attribute - `<p ng-class='{"active" : isActive(params)}'></p>`
2. As CSS class- `<p class='ng-class: isActive(params)'></p>`

The first evlas the expression and sets the class `active` if true.

The second simply takes the returned value of the expression and sets it as a class, so if `isActive()` returnes `active`, that class would be used.

[NgClass Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

This is a valid method for NgClass. It may be because you have added the `{}` into the `ng-class:` definition as well as passing more than an expression.

Try removing the `{}` from each instance like so and updating the `isActive` method to return `active` (the active class) if true and '' (blank) if false:

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class: isActive('/index.html')"  href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</span></a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class: isActive('/aboutus.html')"  href="./aboutus.html"><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About Us</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class: isActive('/contactus.html')" href="./contactus.html"><span class="fa fa-address-book fa-lg"></span> Contact us</a>
</div>

$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
   if(viewLocation === $location.path()) return 'active';
   else return '';
};
```

**OTHER OPTION:**

I recommend using the `attribute Usage` of NgClass. Try to pull it out of the `class` attribute and use it as it's own attribute.

```html
<body ng-app="headerModule">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
               <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" ng-controller="headerContr">
                      <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/index.html')}"  href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</span></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/aboutus.html')}"  href="./aboutus.html"><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About Us</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" ng-class="{active: isActive('/contactus.html')}" href="./contactus.html"><span class="fa fa-address-book fa-lg"></span> Contact us</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </nav>
            <header class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container fluid">
                    <div class="row">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but it didn't work. I tried both ways, as an attribute and also a class..neither worked. I include this header.html in my index.html. just wondering whether that causes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have problem with syntax:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link ng-class:{ active: isActive('/index.html')};"  href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</span></a>
```

`ng-class` must be attribute, not embedded in class attribute .

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/index.html')};" href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</span></a>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.i tried the 'attribute way'. did not work.